# Need to prove that there are $m^{n}$ mappings between two sets. Is my proof formal enough, and if not, what can I improve on?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Here is the proposition:

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ There are $m^{n}$ mappings between a set $A$ and a set $B$, where $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$.

$Proof.$ Let $A$ and $B$ be sets with $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$. Let $a_{i}\in A$. Take this arbitrary element in A and observe that it can be mapped to $m$ different elements, as in, there are $m$ choices for this element. By the rule of product, the amount of mappings from $A$ to $B$ with any two elements in $A$ will be $m\cdot m=m^{2}$, as there are $m$ choices for every element. Continually applying the rule of product yields $m\cdot m \dotsm m\cdot m=m^{n}$. Thus, there are $m^{n}$ mappings between two sets with cardinality $n$ and $m$.

How can I improve this proof and make it more verbose and formal?

Comment: “make it more verbose” Verbosity is not something we aspire to!

Comment: I guess I used the wrong word. What I really meant was making the flow of the proof better and using better words to connect parts of the proof, such as 'hence' or 'thus'.

Comment: But yes, you are definitely right-- a proof should not be shrouded and made more obtuse in verbose language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That proof is  fine. As an instructor, it's just what I would hope to see.  Making it "more verbose and formal" would only make it harder to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words

Answer (score 1):

We need a few preliminary results:

1. For any finite sets $A$ and $B$ and binary partition $\{A', A''\}$ of $A$, $\left|B^A\right| = \left|B^{A'}\right| \times \left|B^{A''}\right|$.
2. For any singleton $A$ and finite set $B$, $\left|B^A\right| = |B|$.

Now, let $K$ be the set of natural numbers $k$
such that, for every set $A$ of size $k$, $\left|B^A\right| = m^k$.
Then, by induction, $K = \mathbf{N}$, since:

1. For any set $A$ of size $0$ (that is, for the empty set), $B^A$ has just one element, the empty mapping, so
   \begin{align*}
   \left|B^A\right| &= 1\\
   &= m^0;
   \end{align*}
   so $0 \in K$.
2. Let $k$ be a member of $K$. Let $A$ be a set of size $k^+$.
   Then, for some objects $A'$ and $a$,
   $A$ is a set of size $k$ and $\{A', \{a\}\}$ is a partition of $A$.
   Then
   \begin{align*}
   \left|B^A\right|
   &= \left|B^{A'}\right| \times \left|B^{\{a\}}\right| && \text{by prelim. result 1}\\
   &= \left|B^{A'}\right| \times |B| && \text{by prelim. result 2}\\
   &= m^k \times m && \text{by inductive hyp.}\\
   &= m^{k^+}.
   \end{align*}
   Since that holds for all sets $A$ of size $k^+$, $k^+ \in K$.
   That is, for every element $k$ of $K$, $k^+ \in K$.

Now, since $n \in \mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{N} = K$, $n \in K$,
so, by construction of $K$, $\left|B^A\right| = m^n$.

Comment: Awesome proof, much more formal, thank you